# How to write same value into 2 Databases?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database

I need to insert the same values into 2 different databases.

What is the best approach in order to do this ? Can I somehow make this using some configurations tweaks, or creating code for each operation is the only way?

I'm mainly using Java + MSSQL.

Comment: Are you want to both database same or only some value want to insert in both database?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Stating why may lead of better answers.  Is your application talking to two disparate databases for some reason?  Or is this two databases with exactly the same schema (i.e. replication)?

Comment: There is an old Informix database right now which crashes a lot. The solution approved is to create a new MSSQL database so that the application saves the data there. So basically the applications saves data both in Informix and MSSQL. I was looking for a simple intuitive solution, without duplicating code etc. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is related to database replication. Since you added sql tag, I can only provide a reference for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

**Edit:**
You have added MSSQL tag, here are the docs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using java with mysql.,
you try this..

```
 String a=database1_name.table_name;
 String b=database2_name.table_name;

 String sql = "INSERT INTO "+a+"VALUES (100, 'Zara', 'Ali', 18)";
 String sql = "INSERT INTO "+b+"VALUES (100, 'Zara', 'Ali', 18)";
```

This should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually did it using triggers. This way, if you wish, you can even insert, update and delete on the two databases at the same time, keeping the two databases synchronized.

Hope this helps.